# How does Abathur contribute to team experience?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Abathur is surely an interesting and unique design, but how exactly does he soak xp when he's in a lane?

- Do my locusts soak xp when I'm on another lane?
- Do I soak 2 lanes worth of xp when minions die to the towers that are just in front of me while I use symbiote on a minion and kill enemy minions on another empty lane?

Comment: I think this and a few other Abathur questions should be merged into one and ideally updated with the latest information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Locusts do not grant the AoE experience like heroes do for just being nearby the death of a unit. Instead, locusts gain experience whenever something dies after it has been damaged by the locust within, I believe, the last 5 seconds. Similarly, your mines also grant experience under the same conditions.

Abathur, in theory, can cover all 3 lanes for their experience because of his long-range abilities. 2-3 mines can easily blow up minion waves in one lane, a pack of locusts can be in another, and he can be nearby the third lane or even cloned at this time.

Comment: I know experience is not multiplied by the number of players nearby. What I meant was if everyone is at bot lane, abathur is at mid lane leeching xp from minions dying nearby while he uses symbiote on top lane and kills minions. This means leeching xp from two lanes by himself, thus twice the experience.

Comment: @Varaquilex You are correct with that. He would earn "Nearby Hero" experience from being in mid, and any units in top lane you damaged would give your team experience too. A very aware Abathur can lane dominate and be a huge experience gain because of this.

Comment: I still feel like the full spectrum of mechanisms remains unclear. Can he double dip on xp, gaining xp from his mines, locusts, and proximity? Also, doesn't he spawn the minions in the same lane he's in, so how can the minions leech from a different lane?

Comment: @rbatt As I understand it, Aba has two methods of full XP soak and two methods of semi-soak. He can fully soak by normal proximity himself, but this also works on his symbiote target. So if he symbiotes a minion in a lane empty of heroes, he is effectively there as well. He can additionally gain Xp through mines and locusts as explained above. Mines and locusts do not gain XP for him from proximity, but from damaging/killing minions.

Comment: So for three lanes, he could be in one, be symbioting a minion in a second, and mining a third. About 5/6 as effective as the Vikings being in all three. His advantage is that he can symbiote/clone a hero to participate in a team fight/objective, while still body-soaking a lane. This is something the Vikings cannot do. It also means that the longer the objective is contested, the more XP Aba soaks from the lane.